# Событие клик на мобильных устройствах

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой

```
$('.click').click(function(){

 // Разные функции
});
```

Не работает на мобильных устройствах с сенсорными экранами. Подскажите, как решить проблему. Может, плохо ищю, но пока ни одно из найденных решений не заработало. Понял пока только то, что на мобильных устройствах событие нажатия работает по-другому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
$('.click').on('click', function(){

 // Разные функции
});
```

Comment: Пробовал, нашел проблему: оказывается, у меня в файле перед кодом есть функция, которая не выполняется на мобильных устройствах из-за того, что не подключается файл для этой функции по специальному условию. Убрал функцию - все заработало.

Comment: `$('...').click(fn)` — это короткая запись для `$('.click').on('click', fn)`.